# Objective-C macro giving a parse error: Expected identifier

Tags: objective-c, macros

The following macro is giving me a parse error. Can't see what's wrong here.

```
 #define adjust(tag, x, y) if (self.tag==tag) { origin.x += x; origin.y += y; return origin; }

  ....

 adjust(20, 28, 265)
```

EDIT:

Look at the attached screenshot. I want to use macro expansion just to improve the code readability. It's a very local usage, hence no risk or reuse etc.

[image]

Comment: is origin a struct? or this is part of Rect?

Comment: The problem is that `if (self.tag==tag)` expands to `if (self.20==20)`, compare the duplicate question for a possible solution.

Comment: Thanks Martin. #define adjust(_tag, _x, _y) if (self.tag==_tag) { origin.x += _x; origin.y += _y; return origin; } did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Your macro refers to an undefined attribute `origin`, which if it doesn't exist in the scope of the replacement, will cause a compiler error after the macro has been expanded. Actually, as a whole, your macro isn't very modular. For example, you have references to `tag` and `self`, which are attributes that

1. Would be very contextual
2. Would cause compilation to fail if they do not occur and have specific meaning after macro expansion has been completed

Comment: +1 like the explanation

Comment: I agree that the macro is not modular. The actual cause for the compiler error however is the unwanted expansion of `self.tag` to `self.20`, not the undefined attribute `origin`, see my comments to the question.

Comment: @MartinR - yes, I agree. If anything, the edits that were made to the question ***after*** I posted my answer illustrate the danger of such a locally scoped macro.